# FCM get registration token via robot framework

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, robotframework

I want to get generated registration token which generated by a client such as (Web JS, Android/IOS App...) via robot todo automation testing

I'm thinking to use mountebank to add JS SDK but not simple because related to grant notification permission issue (It's required to able to generate registration token)

Anybody have an idea to get that token via robot please share

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you sure this is related to robot framework, the test automation framework? (robotframework.org)?

Comment: I want to do FCM automation test by robot framework

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057192/how-do-i-quickly-automate-sending-fcm-or-apns-messages

Answer (score 0):

What is FCM?

Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is a cross-platform messaging solution that lets you reliably send messages at no cost.
Using FCM, you can notify a client app that new email or other data is available to sync. You can send notification messages to drive user re-engagement and retention. For use cases such as instant messaging, a message can transfer a payload of up to 4KB to a client app.

Using deprecated Google Cloud Messaging APIs? Learn more about how to migrate to FCM.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging